# Write numpy.ndarray with Russian characters to file

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas, utf-8

I try to write `numpy.ndarray` to file. 
I use

```
unique1 = np.unique(df['search_term'])
unique1 = unique1.tolist()
```

and next try 
1)

```
edf = pd.DataFrame()
edf['term'] = unique1
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'term.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
edf.to_excel(writer)
writer.close()
```

and 2)

```
thefile = codecs.open('domain.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
for item in unique:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

But all return `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 9: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: Do you mean the title to be *Write numpy.ndarray with **Russian** characters to file*? At present, there's a *u* missing, which makes it difficult to understand what you're asking by looking at the title only.

Answer (score 0):

The second example should work if you encode the strings as utf8.

The following works in Python2 with a utf8 encoded file:

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd

edf = pd.DataFrame()
edf['term'] = ['foo', 'bar', u'русском']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'term.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
edf.to_excel(writer)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]